# Webview not loading again while clicking on the tab again

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I'm working with titanium and developing tabbed application same as kitchen sink

My Home tab loads html data from the json file Here is the code,

```
HomeContent.js

function HomeWindow(title) {
var self = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    title:title,
    backgroundColor:'white'
});
var fileName = 'includes/HomeContent.json';
var file = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory, fileName);
var preParseData = (file.read().text);
var response = JSON.parse(preParseData);
var content = response[0].content;
var webview = Titanium.UI.createWebView({data:content});
self.add(webview);
return self;
};

module.exports = HomeWindow;
```

It is working first time while click again it does not call particular HTML again.

for more reference Here it is my tab generating code, I don't think so it creates any problem,

```
var homewindowWin = new HomeWindow(L('HomeContent'));
var homeTab = Ti.UI.createTab({
    title: L('Home'),
    icon: '/images/tabs/KS_nav_ui.png',
    window: homewindowWin
});
homewindowWin.containingTab = homeTab;
self.addTab(homeTab);
```

Stuck with that any help will be highly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by load event of the tab which assigns again webview see edited code below,

```
function HomeWindow(title) {
var self = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    title:title,
    backgroundColor:'white'
});

 var fileName = 'includes/HomeContent.json'; 
 var file = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory,   fileName);    
 var preParseData = (file.read().text); 
 var response = JSON.parse(preParseData); 
 var content = response[0].content;
 var webview = Titanium.UI.createWebView({data:content});
 var counter = 0;
 webview.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
     counter++;
        if ( counter > 1 ) {
            self.remove(webview);
            webview = null;
            fileName = 'includes/HomeContent.json'; 
             file = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory, fileName);    
             preParseData = (file.read().text); 
             response = JSON.parse(preParseData); 
             content = response[0].content;
        }
        var webview = Titanium.UI.createWebView({data:content});
            self.add(webview);
        });
 self.add(webview);
 return self;
 };

 module.exports = HomeWindow;
```